# How to check width and height before insert image by using [Package CollectionFS]

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

Need help for this.

I have tried upload some image, i would like to check that width and height before insert to db.I stuck when try to check while at lib collection.

thx in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#transformwrite--transformread?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in server side. If you want to do it in client side you can try like this. But not sure about browser support.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL; 
$("#file").change(function (e) { 
  var file, img; 
  if ((file = this.files[0])) {
   img = new Image();
   img.onload = function () { 
      alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
   }; 
   img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
 });
```

Note: I have taken plane js approach. Not using package collection.